# Styling Buttons Created in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this button which is generated in my JS file. I want to style it to be a bootstrap button and add hover, ID and class attributes to it. I am not sure how to do this. This is how I generate my button so far. Do I have to import something into my .js file to use bootstrap? I cannot generate this button in my HTML because it is only shown when another button is clicked.

```js
// here is the button logic
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    var txt = document.createTextNode("Bought");

    btn.appendChild(txt);
    li.appendChild(btn);
```

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: li is not defined",`

Comment: ID: [`element.id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id) or [`.prop('id')`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) – Class: [`element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), [`element.className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className), or [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) – Hover: [`mouseenter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter) and [`mouseleave`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseleave), or [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).

Comment: Why are you creating a button with javascript in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

The button is not styled by default in bootstrap. You should add a class to it to style it. In bootstrap the basic one is `.btn`, but there are more.

Just add this class to your button in javascript.

```
...
btn.className = 'btn';
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first import bootstrap in your html page using link tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Then you can add any bootstrap class using javascript like this:

```
var btn = document.createElement("button");
var txt = document.createTextNode("Bought");
// class name you want to set, bootstrap button class in your case
btn.className = "btn btn-primary";
btn.appendChild(txt); 
li.appendChild(btn);`
```

Answer (score 0):

if bootstrap is not imported import it in your html code and then
        `var attribute=createAttribute("attributeName");`
after that add the value to the attribute
     `attribute.value="value"`
and finally add the attribute to the element
 `element.setAttributeNode(attribute)`

Answer (score -2):

I'm sure this can be done with regular js however here's my solution with jquery. If you don't know what jquery is, it is an extremely useful, easy to use, tool that you should really look up.

```js
 var btn = document.createElement("button");
    var txt = document.createTextNode("Bought");
    var div = document.getElementById("div");

    btn.appendChild(txt);

    $(btn).attr("id", "Btn1");
    $(btn).addClass("btn btn-primary custom"); //add custom to allow hover css
    $(btn).html("Click me");
    
    div.appendChild(btn);
```

```css
.custom : hover {
  /*stuff to do on hover*/
}
```